# Android Notification Not getting Sound And Vibration

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I've used FCM Notifications in My app ,
I'm Receiving Them and it's showing Title And message Perfectly

But,When i'm receiving the Notification Im not getting any sound or vibration or any Led light indication

My Notification Builder Code is

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo);
    builder.setContentTitle(Title);
    builder.setContentText(Message);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setSound(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/notification.mp3"));
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you added permissions in android manifest for vibrate..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **1.** When you send push notification from `firebase` make sure that sound option enabled

like this
[image]

## **2.**  Also make sure that you have added permissions in android manifest for vibrate.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

## **3.**  If you are sending from server than use payload

notification payload of the notification there is a sound key.

From the official documentation its use is:

> Indicates a sound to play when the device receives a notification. Supports default or the filename of a sound resource bundled in the app. Sound files must reside in /res/raw/.

```
{
    "to" : ".......",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "body",
      "title" : "title",
      "icon" : "myicon",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm Sending Notification from a WebServer using Php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(alarmSound);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you have to add permissions in manifest file like below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: Added But The problem still Exists

Answer (score 0):

> Android Notification Not getting Sound And Vibration

Try to use default [RingtoneManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

**Remove** `builder.setSound(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/notification.mp3"));`

```
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(uri);
```

Added permissions in android manifest for vibrate.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**Important Note:** *Make sure Android Push Notification Service correctly configure by cloud server-side(GCM/Firebase)*

**Confirm that you are getting correct payload for downstream (JSON)**

```
 {
      "to": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "notification": {
        "body": "great match!",
        "title": "SamDev Test",
        "icon": "myicon",
        "sound": "default"
      }
    }
```