# Custom Sound Not Playing Firebase Messaging Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Custom Notification sound in my android application. I have checked all related questions and answers in stackoverflow but I am not able to figure why its not playing my custom sound in application. My code for notification is like below.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

    }
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
    }

}

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {

}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Context context = getBaseContext();
    String channelId = "raj";
    int sound_notification = context.getSharedPreferences("setting", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("sound_notification", 1);
    Uri MyCustomSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/sound" + (sound_notification));
    //Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(MyCustomSound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    //notificationBuilder.setSound(MyCustomSound);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Raj",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I have tried to send notification from My Server with PHP as well from Firebase Console but its always play default sound instead my custom sound. Let me know if someone can help me for out from the issue.
Thanks

Comment: please check when app is in foregound(Means app is open) then you got any your notification sound or not?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586285/7666442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/sound/" + R.raw.sound);
    mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/sound/" + R.raw.sound));
```