# Firebase notificacion sound / vibration when app in background with Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

I can't get sound or vibration when app in background with Android Oreo. With app in foreground sound and vibration works fine.

With previous versions of android and without Nofication Channel everything worked fine but now I don't find the way to do this.

This is my code:

```
private void showNotification(String title, String body) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.name.notification.test";

    Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_sound);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .build();

        notificationChannel.setDescription("EDMT Channel");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});           
        notificationChannel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes); // This is IMPORTANT            
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586215/android-notification-not-getting-sound-and-vibration/46586285#46586285

Comment: Added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` but same problem, in background mode no sound / vibration

Answer (score 0):

**i found this in the documentation. May be it will help you :**

- > On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and above, importance of a notification
  >   is determined by the importance of the channel the notification was
  >   posted to. Users can change the importance of a notification channel
  >   in the system settings (figure 12). On Android 7.1 (API level 25) and
  >   below, importance of each notification is determined by the
  >   notification's priority.
- > Android O introduces notification channels to provide a unified system
  >   to help users manage notifications. When you target Android O, you
  >   must implement one or more notification channels to display
  >   notifications to your users. If you don't target Android O, your apps
  >   behave the same as they do on Android 7.0 when running on Android O
  >   devices.

> **1**. Individual notifications must now be put in a specific channel.
>
> **2**. Users can now turn off notifications per channel, instead of turning
>       off all notifications from an app.
>
> **3**. Apps with active notifications display a notification "badge" on top
>       of their app icon on the home/launcher screen.
>
> **4**. Users can now snooze a notification from the drawer. You can set an
>       automatic timeout for a notification.
>
> **5**. Some APIs regarding notification behaviors were moved from
>       Notification to NotificationChannel. For example, use
>       NotificationChannel.setImportance() instead of
>       NotificationCompat.Builder.setPriority() for Android 8.0 and higher.

Comment: Putting in the actual link of the documentation would be helpful.